# Error when integrating passkey with Android

Tags: android, android-studio, wso2, wso2-identity-server, passkey

I'm currently working on implementing passkey authentication for an Android application, using this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys#kotlin

For authentication, I'm using the WSO2 identity server, but here's where I'm doing something different. Instead of the app creating the passkey, the WSO2 identity server does it, and I store the passkey on the device.

Here's a weird behavior I'm encountering: the app isn't prompting me for the passkeys registered in the app. Instead, it shows a QR code for signing in with passkeys stored on other devices. After that, I get a GetCredentialCancellationException thrown.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are some more details about the process:

- I set requestJson to:

  {
  "challenge":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "allowCredentials":[],
  "Timeout":1800000,
  "userVerification": "Required",
  "rpId":"abc.com"
  }
- Both the challenge and rpId come from the WSO2 identity server.
- I'm not setting a digital assets link, as I'm using a separate
  identity server for authentication.

Can anyone help me to debug, what I have done wrong here ?

Comment: digital assets link is the problem you have to host you digital assets link file.

Comment: Do we have a way to override this inter dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: keys and values in the JSON are case sensitive, so `Timeout` and `Required` are both incorrect.

If you haven't set up the digital asset links, things won't work so try that first. (I.e. your app will need permission to use credentials from abc.com before things will work.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the use still doesn't have any passkeys registered. Note that the `GetCredentialRequest` there is a parameter `setPreferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials` that set this behavior, by [google](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys#:%7E:text=If%20you%20set%20preferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials%20to%20true%20and%20there%20are%20no%20immediately%20available%20credentials%2C%20Credential%20Manager%20won%27t%20show%20any%20UI%20and%20the%20request%20will%20fail%20immediately%2C%20returning%20NoCredentialException%20for%20get%20requests%20and%20CreateCredentialNoCreateOptionException%20for%20create%20requests):

> If you set preferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials to true and there are
> no immediately available credentials, Credential Manager won't show
> any UI and the request will fail immediately, returning
> NoCredentialException for get requests and
> CreateCredentialNoCreateOptionException for create requests